# how do I make listview respond to touch in react-native

Tags: listview, react-native

Wrap it in touchable will disable scrolling.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <listview/>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Wrap rendered row in touchable will make it. But the listview may not be  filled with rows.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to make the rows that the lisview touchable? If so, why are you wrapping everything in a TouchableWithoutFeedback? Thanks.

Comment: @NaderDabit Because the listview is not full of rows. There may be blank space without rows wrapped in the Touchable. If you touch the blank space, there won't be any action respond to you.